# Export Datatable to Word Document With Page Numbers using Open XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, openxml

My requirement is : Exporting a dynamic DataTable to Word document with Page Numbers
We need to use Open XML to achieve this. 
I have code to export Datatable to Word. And also to insert page numbers.

I got Below code code to export datatable

```
public void CreateWordtable(string filename,DataTable data)
{
    WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainDocPart.Document = new Document();
    Body body = new Body();
    mainDocPart.Document.Append(body);
    //rinks@::creating new table

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table table = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table();            
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < data.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Append(new Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(data.Rows[i][j].ToString()))));
            cell.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "1200" }));
            row.Append(cell);
        }
        table.Append(row);
    }
    body.Append(table);
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    doc.Dispose();
}
```

And below code is to insert page numbers in a word document

```
private static void AddPageNumberFooters(WordprocessingDocument parent)
{
    string documentPath = @"D:\EmptyDoc.docx";
    using (WordprocessingDocument package =
        WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
    {
        var mainDocumentPart = parent.AddMainDocumentPart();
        GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainDocumentPart);

        var documentSettingsPart =
            mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart
            <DocumentSettingsPart>("rId1");

        GenerateDocumentSettingsPart().Save(documentSettingsPart);

        var firstPageFooterPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("rId1");
        GeneratePageFooterPart("Page 1 of 2").Save(firstPageFooterPart);

        var secondPageFooterPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("rId2");
        GeneratePageFooterPart("Page 2 of 2").Save(secondPageFooterPart);
    }
}


private static Document GenerateMainDocumentPart()
{
    var element =
        new Document(
            new Body(
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Text("Page 1 content"))
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new LastRenderedPageBreak(),
                        new Text("Page 2 content"))
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })
                ),
                new SectionProperties(
                    new FooterReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.First,
                        Id = "rId1"
                    },
                    new FooterReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even,
                        Id = "rId2"
                    },
                    new PageMargin()
                    {
                        Top = 1440,
                        Right = (UInt32Value)1440UL,
                        Bottom = 1440,
                        Left = (UInt32Value)1440UL,
                        Header = (UInt32Value)720UL,
                        Footer = (UInt32Value)720UL,
                        Gutter = (UInt32Value)0UL
                    },
                    new TitlePage()
                )));

    return element;
}


private static Header GeneratePageHeaderPart(string HeaderText)
{
    var element =
        new Header(
            new Paragraph(
                new ParagraphProperties(
                    new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" }),
                new Run(
                    new Text(HeaderText))
            ));

    return element;
}
```

My problem is, I have combine above both methods to export data along with page numbers.
if we know there are 2 pages in the word document, i can insert 2 FooterParts.
But i don't know how many pages will be created after exporting the data.

Comment: word of advice do not use the following when working with Microsoft.Interop `doc.Dispose();` for example Google how to use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` also have you checked there documentation to see if you can determine how many pages are there totally when creating footers etc.. looks like you will need to refactor the code to handle that portion

Comment: @DJKRAZE: He's using OpenXML, not Word Interop. In general, if it implements IDisposible, then it needs to be disposed. He'd do better in a `using` block, though.

Comment: Total Oversight John I agree also about the `using` block

Comment: Can't you use C# code to generate a footer part with automatic page numbering?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to automatically add page numbers:

```
  private static string GenerateFooterPartContent(WordprocessingDocument package, string text = null)
    {
        FooterPart footerPart1 = package.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.FirstOrDefault();
        if (footerPart1 == null)
        {
            footerPart1 = package.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();
        }

        var relationshipId = package.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart1);
        // Get SectionProperties and set HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id
        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties();
        FooterReference footerReference2 = new FooterReference() { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = relationshipId };
        sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference2);
        package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);


        Footer footer1 = new Footer();

        var r = new Run();
        PositionalTab positionalTab2 = new PositionalTab() { Alignment = AbsolutePositionTabAlignmentValues.Right, 
            RelativeTo = AbsolutePositionTabPositioningBaseValues.Margin, 
            Leader = AbsolutePositionTabLeaderCharValues.None };

        r.Append(positionalTab2);
        paragraph2.Append(r);

        r = new Run(new Text("Page: ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve },
              // *** Adaptation: This will output the page number dynamically ***
              new SimpleField() { Instruction = "PAGE" },
              new Text(" of ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve },
              // *** Adaptation: This will output the number of pages dynamically ***
              new SimpleField() { Instruction = "NUMPAGES" });
        paragraph2.Append(r);

        footer1.Append(paragraph2);

        footerPart1.Footer = footer1;
        return relationshipId;
    }
```